# Is there a way, through MVVM and XAML, to stretch the rows in a DataGrid to take up all the space vertically?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I am currently developing a 'Who Wants To Be A Millionaire' Showrunner using C# and XAML languages, and currently I've binded the list of amounts to a DataGrid, which is applicable to the Host, Contestant and Graphics screen.

But the issue I'm having at the moment, is that I can't seem to find a way to stretch the items (rows) to take up the space, vertically, inside the DataGrid.

This is what I've got for now, for both Host and Contestants screens, It may not be great, but it's a start. (I'm still pretty new to XAML and MVVM)

```
            <DataGrid x:Name="tree" ItemsSource="{Binding moneyList}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="450,178,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="190" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="#ff8800" HeadersVisibility="None" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" GridLinesVisibility="None" Height="302">
                <DataGrid.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                        <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding contestantOn}" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ff8800"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding milestone}" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#fbe1b8"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding contestantOn}" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#ff8800"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.Resources>
                <DataGrid.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Views/Images/MtreeBG.jpg"/>
                </DataGrid.Background>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Width="22" Header="QNumber" Binding="{Binding qNumber}" FontFamily="/Views/Fonts/Copperplate Condensed SSi Condensed.ttf#Copperplate SSi" FontSize="16">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding contestantOn}" Value="true">
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFBE4BA"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Width="5" Header="Diamond" Binding="{Binding diamond}" FontFamily="/Views/Fonts/WINGDING.TTF#Wingdings" FontSize="10" Foreground="#FFFFFF">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,1,0,0"/>
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                <Setter Property="LayoutTransform" Value="{StaticResource FontStretchCondensed}" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Amount" Binding="{Binding amount}" FontFamily="/Views/Fonts/Copperplate Condensed SSi Condensed.ttf#Copperplate SSi" FontSize="16"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

If there is a way to stretch the rows to fill up the space on the DataGrid, that would be awesome! I am open to alternatives as well if there isn't a way to do so in DataGrid.

Many thanks!

Comment: The thing that contains the rows in a datagrid is called an itemspanel. The default is a virtualising stackpanel. You could try making it a uniformgrid or wrappanel instead. If you google you'll probably find loads of examples do this with an itemscontrol substituting a canvas or some other panel. Datagrid inherits from itemscontrol.

Comment: That actually helped a lot! Many thanks!